# Testing methodology for USB driver

Tags: testing, usb, driver

We are developing an windows application which interacts with an USB device for data. The device driver is obtained from an third party.

Our application works well in all systems except two to three Windows 8 PC. 
Problem seen in those 3 pcs were :
1) Driver for the Device is installed and found in device manager but couldn't initialize the USB device (During initialization, we create an interface for additional end point)

These kind of problem is not reproducible in our testing PC but only in our 3 customer PC (not all PCs!)

We cannot test our application in all PCs , tablets, (with windows 7, 8 etc..) in the market to ensure that it works.

So,My question here is, what test strategy (setup) should we follow to confirm that the our application works in all PCs tablets with windows version.

Any ideas?

@DavidGrayson : Yes you are correct, may be i'll give you more details:   What type of PC should i use to test the driver... should i setup PCs with different USB Controllers? How about Windows driver kit that comes along Visual studio? Can we test third party driver with it?

Comment: I don't think there is any good way to do this besides getting a variety of computers to test it on, and testing it yourself.  I would question whether you really need to develop your own driver; maybe you should try using libusb or WinUSB, since those have been tested more widely.